# Does expired access_token affect photo upload and ability to post status?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app's access_token will expire in 60 days according to fb documentation.

When I try to post the status to the user profile it works correctly without an accesstoken

my code

```
if ($user_id) {
  try {
    $post_url = '/' . $user_id . '/feed';
    $msg_body = array(
      'link'=> $link,
      'picture'=> $picture,
      'name'=> $linkname,
      'caption'=> $caption,
      'description'=> $description,
      'message' => $userMessage
    );
    $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

but when I upload a photo to a user profile it doesn't work without the access token

```
if ($user_id) {
  try {
    $post_url = '/' . $user_id . '/photos';
    $access = $row['access'] ;
    $msg_body = array(
      'access_token'=>$access,
      'source'=>'@'.$userPhoto,
      'message' => $userMessage
    );

    $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

my app permissions:

```
$fbPermissions = 
    'publish_stream,photo_upload,user_photos,read_stream,email,user_birthday';
```

The question is: if an access token expires, does it affect the ability of my app to post status and upload photos to a user's profile?
Will it affect both of them or upload a photo only?